# Authorize record associations in pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, pundit

How do we go about authorizing associations when creating and updating records with pundit in rails.

For example if we're updating a `comment` record that belongs to a `post`, we need to make sure the user has the permission to access that post or else it's a security breach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `create` action you can do like:

```
def create
  authorize @comment.post # this checks the authorization of Post
  authorize @comment # and then for comment
  #.. then code to create the comment
end
```